# Trying to do a loop in a excel userform n times until a condition is met, and place in a different rwo the data intruduced in the textbox

Tags: excel, while-loop, userform

I do not manage to write the data in different rows it keeps placing each introduced data in the first row

```
private sub commandbutton1_click()
dim contar as variant
dim a=1
do while a <= contar
sheets("datos").range("j" & a+1) = textbox1
textbox=""`your text`
a=a+1
loop
end sub
```

Comment: Nothing has capital letters so I'm assuming you typed it manually in here? contar doesn't have a value, `dim a=1` should throw an error as well, that should be ´Dim a As Long: a=1´ and I've got no clue what you're trying to do with `textbox=""`

Comment: hello you are right i typed manually as i was coding in a different machine, let me copy here now working in the same machinePrivate Sub CommandButton1_Click(), textbox1="" clears the textbox windown after first data is introduced

Dim contar As Variant
Dim a As Integer
contar = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheets("datos").Range("a1:a150")) - 1
a = 1
Do While a <= contar
'For a = 1 To contar - 1
'MsgBox (contar - 1)
Sheets("datos").Range("j" & a + 1) = TextBox1
'MsgBox (TextBox1)
TextBox1 = ""
a = a + 1
MsgBox "a= " & (a)

Loop
'Next a
End Sub

Answer (score 0):

hello i think i have solved it myself with a different approach

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim contar As Integer
Dim check As Integer
check = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheets("datos").Range("j2:j150"))

contar = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheets("datos").Range("a1:a150")) 
- 1
  If check <= contar Then
  Sheets("datos").Range("j" & check + 2) = TextBox1
  TextBox1 = ""
  End If
  End Sub
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be comparing the same size ranges? And why the hardcoded "a150"/"j150", do you mean to check for the last row? Your current code will only fill in one cell now with the textbox' value, I thought you had several rows you wanted to fill?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).